# php mail does not work with no-gmail address

Tags: php, html, email, gmail, bcc

I have part of my project when my clients will reseive mail after so many actions, when I testing my mail function, I have problem when the adresse is to "gmail" , I reseive the mail, but when the mail is no-gmail, the mail not reseived !!! :( this is my mail function:

```
function emailDemande($email, $name, $nameL){

    $subject = 'Votre demande ';

    $headers = "From: XXX <contact@emoovio.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc: abdelkhalek.oumaya@gmail.com, TEST@DOMAIN.com\r\n";
   // $headers = 'From: XXX <'. $from. '>\r\n';
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    $message='htmlmessage';

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
};
```

Comment: So `mail()` is returning true? If so, it's not a PHP issue.

Answer (score 1):

Mail is very complex in his flow.

## Your Mail Headers and Content

- Does the sender mail address exist as mailbox or as forwarder? Sending mail with a non-existent mail address goes wrong.
- What about the mail headers, subject and body? More info: https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/

## The Sending Mail Server

Be sure the sending server (the smtp server) knows and allows the sender mail address to mail from.

## Blacklist

Check if your smtp server is blacklisted. More info: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

## External Mail Service

- I recommend to use external mail services, like Mailgun (http://mailgun.com). Mailgun provides an API for sending, receiving and tracking mail. A great advantage is that your own mail server (or global ip) cannot be blacklisted.
- For testing your mail functionality, you can use Mailtrap (https://mailtrap.io).